# Tag Request: God Machine Rules Update

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

I would like to request that someone with higher privileges than me create some or all of the the following tags, and mark them as aliases.

- God-Machine
- God-Machine-Rules-Update
- nnwod
- nwod-GMC
- wod-2.5
- new new world of darkness
- new new wod

As far as I can tell there is no commonly used acronym for it,
thus my suggestion for many aliases.
Informally I having seen "new new wod" quiet often in conversation.
and the book itself it s called "World of Darkness: The God Machine Rules Update"

There are some questions that are appropriate only to it, and no to `nwod` questions.
an example of use would be my question: [Removing Conditions without resolution](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/30810/removing-conditions-without-resolution)

Comment: As per the answer. Preemptively making synonyms would be an infinite job.

Comment: Shouldn't this be status-accepted?
I requested one or more tags, and one tag was created.

Comment: @Oxinabox That is probably more because of the synonym request, and it's better that way so people don't get confused and think we do it that way.

Comment: Ah right, fair enough.
I have my tag, now I am happy.

Answer (score 7):

Tag creation and synonym creation are generally done *reactively*, not proactively.

A **new tag** can be added when a need for it arises: i.e. when there's actually a question that exists or is being created that needs the tag. Whoever first creates such a tag will probably use whatever feels natural to them, which is going to be a decent candidate for the tag we should keep (or it should be an indicator as to what tag we should use).

**Tag synonyms** work the same way: we don't need to pre-emptively create them. We can afford to let new tags arise which *should* be synonyms, and only make them synonyms once they actually get created.

---

I've added the [nwod-god-machine](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwod-god-machine) tag to your question, since that seems to me to be the most intuitive and concise way to tag that update.